# Weird authentication error from Active Directory Win 2008R2

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am trying to do a ldap query from a OpenBSD client to windows 2008R2 active directory and I am getting this error,"49: Invalid credentials". I don't understand why if I tried the same username and password from a windows 7 client and it worked. here is a screenshot of my login.conf and the error I am getting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/raVoc.jpg and this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPuFa.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I haven't set up a *nix client but you can try specifying the username in the following formats:

1. domain\user
2. user@domain.com
3. distinguished name

Also, the connection is occurring over TCP389 which means your credentials may be traversing the network in clear text. This will be helpful for troubleshooting but when everything is working switch it to LDAPS (TCP636).